# $scope.value does not update with a view

Tags: angularjs, slider

I have been trying all and nothing. I wanted create simple circle slider from values with my service, but $scope.value didn't update my view. Take a look at my demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/gh42tqxs/11/

```
<div ng-app="mainApp">
  <div ng-controller="FooController">
     <ui-knob  value="value" options="options" knob-format  data-note="{{note}}"></ui-knob>
  </div>
</div> 

var app = angular.module("mainApp",['ui.knob']);

app.service('Service', function ($http, $q) {
    this.Get = function (premiereId) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var req = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/63xhr',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }
        $http(req).then(function (response) {
            if (response.status == 200) {
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
            }
            else {
                deferred.reject(response.data);
            }
        }, function (error) {
            deferred.reject(error.data);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
})

app.controller("FooController", function (Service, $timeout, $scope) {
        function test() {
        Service.Get().then(function (response) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                console.log(response);
                $scope.value = response.Number;
                $scope.options.min = response.NumberMin;
                $scope.options.max = response.NumberMax;
            }, 1000);
      })
    }
    test();
});
```

Animation isn't starting, we start with the minimum value, not from $scope.value.

ng knob == jquery knob slider

How fix it? Please help me.

Comment: Using `$q.defer()` with `$http` is an anti-pattern since `$http` methods already return a promise

Comment: Hard to help without knowing how `knob` works. Provide link to source for the directive

Comment: @charlietfl Ok i fix it when I will know the answer why my slider not working. Thanks for the advice. https://radmie.github.io/ng-knob/

Comment: OK, answer: <input ng-if="value != null" (...)/>.